# Get Redux state values

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

**EDIT: I think the issue is with my reducers**
**I only have one reducer called "filmsReducer" where I do this at the end :**

```
export default combineReducers({
  films: filmsReducer
});
```

I'm doing an app in React Native using Redux,

I want to get the initialState values below in a component :

```
const initialState = {
  name: "",
  likedFilms: [299534, 49530, 629],
  dislikedFilms: [100241, 559969]
};

const filmsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { likedFilms, dislikedFilms } = state;
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_FILM:
      if (action.array === "like") {
        const newLikedFilms = [...state.likedFilms, action.payload];

        return {
          ...state,
          likedFilms: newLikedFilms
        };
      } else {
        const newDislikedFilms = [...state.dislikedFilms, action.payload];

        return {
          ...state,
          dislikedFilms: newDislikedFilms
        };
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And here's the component, I want to get likedFilms array from the redux state in the props of this component, but the console log doesn't work :

```
class LikedScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.likedFilms); <-- doesn't work
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  likedFilms: state.likedFilms
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LikedScreen);
```

Comment: What's the name of your reducer?

Comment: the name is FilmsReducer

Comment: Have you added `filmsReducer` to the rootReducer?

Comment: Try logging your state - state.likedFilms is undefined, because likedFilms is not your reducer, hence not your state.

Comment: @Dan I don't have a rootReducer, only a filmsReducer and at the bottom of the filmsReducer, I use combineReducers({ films: filmsReducer })

Comment: Can you please say what's the value of `state` in your mapStateToProps?

Comment: why not using functional components?

Comment: @Konstantin my state is not available in the component, there's no value, I show you the export of my reducer in the edit in the first lines of my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your comment, you probably have to adapt your code to the following:

**Edit** Regarding another comment of yours, you need to change it to films instead of FilmsReducer:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  likedFilms: state.films.likedFilms
});
```

Comment: thank you it works, because of the way I named my reducer in the export of the FilmsReducer.js

Answer (score 0):

It will be like, use reducer name as while mapping props in Component

```
class LikedScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.likedFilms); <-- doesn't work
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  likedFilms: state.films.likedFilms
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LikedScreen);
```

Comment: it says TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.filmsReducer.likedFilms'), I only have one reducer : the filmsReducer

Comment: it might be because you didn't register this reducer in root reducer

Comment: ok so I will always need a rootReducer ? I can't juste use my filmsReducer ?

Comment: that was because you registered your filmsReducer with the name films in `combineReducers({ films: filmsReducer }) `

Comment: okkkkk so in the mapStateToProps, I have to put likedFilms: state.films.likedFilms